# Any information about Rabbi Barnett Hasden's "Ner Tamid K" hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

Does anyone here know anything about the reliability of "Rabbi Barnett Hasden of Ner Tamid K in Staten Island, NY"?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you ask your Rabbi questions like this.

Comment: @issac wouldit be better if the question was which certification it's comparable to in terms of standards?

Comment: @yydl, The question is actually not so bad as-is. It asks for information that could be useful. I'd just recommend that you check with your Rabbi before acting on said information. I suppose the question could be objectivized a bit by rephrasing as "What do authoritative rabbis or organizations say about the reliability of this hechsher?" and/or "How does this hechsher's standards differ from those of more widely-known hechshers?"

Comment: With the exception of cheeses, lentils, beans, etc. are the remainder of the products like the oriental noodle bowl reliably kosher? Tablet K is a fairly reliable hecksher.

Comment: @EllenGreenberg, Welcome to Judaism.SE! I converted your answer into a comment because it doesn't really answer the question. If you want to post a follow-up question, please do so [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Also, please consider registering your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features, including the ability to post comments like this one.

Comment: As noted in a Mishpacha magazine article a few months ago, that included a round table discussion by several kashrus experts, the most acceptable hechshers are those who communicate and share information on policies and procedures, and even problems they experience, with the rabbis of other hechshers as well as local rabbeim.  Those who keep quiet tend to be not recommended because rabbis have no basis for making a recommendation.

Comment: "Recommended" by *whom?*

Comment: @Shmuel Dunno. Ask the guy who edited it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I was to compare it to another hechsher, it would be Tablet K. There is a lot of rumour and controversy surrounding the reliability and acceptance of the Ner Tamid K (Rabbi Hasden). It is, in general, not considered as reliable as the OU/OK/CRC, but the best thing to do would be to ask your LOR (Local Orthodox Rabbi).

Comment: Additional possibly relevant information: I have only ever seen Ner Tamid K on restaurants which have already lost their previous hashgacha over some other issue.

Answer (score 5):

Well consider [this](http://nymag.com/news/intelligencer/16589/):

> Staten Island rabbi Dov Hazdan has been granting his own kosher certification to city Dunkin’ Donuts franchises that have served bacon, ham, and sausage, the trayf trifecta. “The meats all come prepackaged,” says Hazdan. “The employees have to wear gloves. I do not condone mixing kosher with nonkosher.” In Manhattan, Hazdan has also given his ner tamid K stamp to Pongal Vegetarian, an Indian restaurant that operates during the Jewish Sabbath

I'm really not sure what to make of the first one (I'm trying to be Melamed Zchus, but if someone else can actually state a justification that would be great), but the second one isn't a Kosher issue per se, it is more a problematic behavior on the part of the certifier.

The bottom line is that it is pretty clear from a story like this that this is a certifier that is very lenient (as compared to what people are generally used to in other certifications). Ask your own Rabbi if that approach is compatible with your general level of observance.

Comment: I'm **guessing** that he's assuming that if they regularly change gloves then no _b'ein_ will ever end up on your donut. Do we know what items in the store the certification covered?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know what he certified, but if I had to guess, it would be the donuts (which are generally dairy). The meat goes into sandwiches sold separately.

Comment: So if it's just the donuts and lets assume any ovens for the donuts are specialized, then there shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: According to a friend whose family owns some of the Dunkin Donuts franchises in Massachusetts, the donuts are made in a seperate factory. Sorry, no source.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, It is possible that the arrangement is basically it is all pre-made food, and order the Kosher stuff if you keep Kosher kind of thing. Not really sure what the gloves have to do with it, then.

Comment: Yishai, FWIW, I've seen numerous places in NYC with partial hashgachot which also serve food which is obviously treif.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is it's generally not up to the usual standards you may be used to. I believe he is more lenient with the definition of kosher cheese than what passes these days.

Answer (score 4):

I have spoken with Rabbi Barnett Hasdan myself and his response was that everything is under his strict kosher supervision. He is a student of the late Rav Moshe Feinshtein z"l and he told me that if I wanted to know if he was a *ne'eman* then I could call Rav Reuven Feinshtein shlit"a and ask him. He also informed me that Rav Reuven eats all of Amy's pareve products, but ONLY due to the fact that Rav Reuven is strict on *Halav Yisrael* and NOT because the cheese products are not kosher. Further, I am aware of Haredi *mashgihim* who work for the OU who also eat pareve Amy's products in their home, but avoid the dairy products due to the issue of them not being *Halav Yisrael*.

I challenge anyone reading this who is a *yireh shamayim* to simply pick up a phone and call Rabbi Hasdan yourself. If after a conversation with this obviously religious (read, "Orthodox") Jewish man you are still not satisfied then by all means feel free to continue to abstain from eating the products he supervises. However, it is does not become all of a sudden *mutar* to spread rumors about his kosher certification which almost certainly jeopardizes his *parnasah*. To do so is a very grave sin.

The politics and arguments over kashrus certification are almost **never** *le-shem shamayim*. Anyone who knows about the intense competition and mud-slinging which often accompanies the determination of who is a religious enough Jew to supervise kosher food and who is not knows this to be the case.

The words which the Ramba"m wrote in a letter to his son, Rabbenu Avraham ring very true to this discussion:

> “Do not engage in *mahloqeth* which makes one’s nefesh
>   disgusting...*Mahloqeth* destroys bodily health, peace of mind, and
>   money. What is left? I have seen pure ones blackened, families plagued
>   and communities disbanded, pious ones lost, the faithful destroyed,
>   the honorable undeservedly shamed - all from *mahloqeth*. Prophets
>   have prophesied, the wise offered insight and philosophers probed, but
>   they still have not plumbed the awful horrors of *mahloqeth*..."
>
> “Therefore, despise *mahloqeth* and flee it. Distance yourself from
>   all its lovers and friends. Be proud of restraint. Know the greatness
>   of forbearance, which is genuine *gevurah* and victory. In this
>   manner, you will be sanctified even in the eyes of your enemies, who
>   will appreciate your greatness of spirit..."

*Mori Yusef Qafih z"l* once stated that many of the differences in *halakhah* which we face between religious Jews are merely *DeRabbanan*, while the *issur* of arousing a *mahloqeth* is from the *Torah* itself. Think about this.

May we all be *zokheh* to put away damaging speech, distance ourselves completely from *mahloqeth*, and treat each other with the dignity and respect due a fellow Jew.

*Kol tuv*.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Your second comment is unproductive. Your third comments is clearly addressed in the post ("but ONLY due to the fact that Rav Reuven is strict on Halav Yisrael and NOT because the cheese products are not kosher"). Your first comment is valid.

Comment: No, I have not yet contacted him, but in all honesty I do not need to. This is like Rash"i's comment on the parashah of the spies, i.e. I already asked if I could take the donkey on the hills, rocks, etc. and was told yes each time. In other words, if he is willing to claim something - in our times of unprecedented telecommunications - about Rav Feinshtein then I can trust that the statement is true. That is, unless we have completely lost the trust which the halakhah ascribes to Jews who are shomrei Torah u-Misswoth, has wa-shalom. Kol tuv.

Comment: Mr. Brin, it is obvious how you feel about me ever since the comment on Chabad-Lubavitch and self-fulfilling prophecy by your detracting comments on almost everything that I post. However, I was not dealing with "clarifying hazaqoth" (whatever that means since the whole purpose of establishing hazaqoth is so that one may confidently rely on them), but rather the cavalier manner in which people "pasul" one another, and particularly in the area of hekhsherim and kashrus supervisors.

Comment: Hekhsherim who are not "big players" and who do not "play ball" with the massive amounts of humroth which have been implemented by the kashrus industry - many times, it seems, to further secure the need for their services - are discounted and otherwise righteous Jews are given all manner of disgusting epithets. The fact is that no one should rely on hearsay when they can simply pick up the phone and decide for themselves. No one needs to be angry about an Orthodox rabbi making decisions regarding kosher that do not fit wit their own views. If you do not want to eat Amy's no one is forcing you.

Comment: But arousing mahloqeth is not a viable answer to kashrus questions. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist please hold the ad hominem out of this.

Comment: It is not all "politics."  As I noted in another comment, the hechshers who share information on their procedures, policies and even the difficulties they encounter, are the ones who are respected and recommended.  Some of the solo-rabbi agencies suffer from lack of experience and, according to Rabbi Moshe Heisler, they forget that the standard a kashrus agency must follow is everything must be OK l'hatchilah (before the fact) -- leniencies that would be permitted b'dieved (after the fact) are meant for resolving issues resulting from accidents.

Comment: @BruceJames "a kashrus agency must follow" ??? Isn't that up to the Rabbi to decide what he must follow?

Comment: @DoubleAA Rabbi Heisler is the exec. dir. of ACKO, an organization that sets best practices for community kashrus agencies. My point: some agencies don't follow best practices, and therefore, they are less respected. The example I referred to was one where an agency did not confirm that the railroad cars used to transport vegetable oil had not previously carried non-kosher animal oils because they assumed what was left was batul. If you know it was there, you can't rely on bitul. When a rabbi give a hechshur, he is certifying l'hathilah that everything is kosher and cannot rely on bitul.

Comment: @BruceJames There are no "objective best practices". Rabbi Heisler is just as entitled to a halachik opinion as whatever rabbi certified those cars. You should ask your LOR whom you can rely on. All the organizations in the world can make up their own standards and it won't change the Halacha. When and when not to rely on Bittul is a complex question and different rabbis may have different opinions. That's ok. (I agree with you about sharing whatever standard they hold of publicly, but I disagree with calling certain standards "better" than others.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Basically you're supporting the standard that having the title "Rabbi" entitles him to decide for himself what is the halacha. So, let me use another real-world case. Canning factory packs "clam chowder" in its factory in week 1, but the amount of clams in each can is less than 1/6. Would halacha require that you kasher the plant before certifying a kosher run of soup in week 2? Or would you be OK certifying the run because the amount of clams in the Week 1 run was de minimus? R. Heisler says if you knew of the clam run, you have to kasher. If not, you don't have to pull the product.

Comment: @doubleaa Anyway, I'm explaining the thinking of rabbis who don't trust heksher X -- I am not telling you that you can or cannot rely on heksher X.

Comment: @BruceJames Come on, man, just because I don't think the OU has a monopoly on deciding Jewish law doesn't mean I think anyone who calls himself a rabbi is knowledgeable. And you should cut it out with your silly "scary stories". Until you show me in **Shulchan Aruch** why the psak **must** be wrong, your stories are just playing with the minds of people who have never learned Yoreh Deah. That's low. If those who don't trust a Hekhsher are thinking "I disagree with position X" that's fine. If their thinking is "Rabbi X is by definition stupid because he disagrees with me" then that is stupider.

Comment: Just to let you all know, I did call Rav Reuven Feinstein about this question and was told that although Rabbi Hasdan does daven in their yeshivah, he was not in the business of certifying the validty of kashrus agencies. And it was left at that. Take from it what you wish. Although it was not surprising at all that this was his response. I have had almost this very thing happen to me when I tell people that they can speak to a certain rav about what I hold with whom I am close. Rabbis like recluse themselves for political reasons. Politics are not kashruth or halakhah. Kol tuv.

Comment: I spoke to R' Reuven recently and was told he doe NOT eat Amy's products at all. So this whole post is based on falsehoods.

Comment: @TheAsh the whole post sound genuine to me, it's from 2013, you spoke to him 6 years later, not sure what happened in between, but it could be that you were both right and just describing answers from two given periods of time.

Answer (score -1):

I think some specific issues rather than vague generalities would be more productive. Yoplait states that Rabbi Hasden certifies their Yogurt, and that it contains gelatin derived from Kosher beef.

(note that Yoplait only has a KD, not a certified symbol)

Comment: Why would gelatin be a problem with milk? It's from bones. You've only said enough to someone who doesn't know anything about Kashrut.

Comment: There are two opinions in Gelatin - one is that it has to be from Kosher slaughtered animals, and the other is that it doesn't (it is so far from food anymore that it doesn't even need to be Kosher). However, in any event (especially according to the second) it would be Pareve. You can find opinions that make it meat, but you would have to look far and wide to find a certifier that wouldn't call it pareve. However, for a company the size of Yoplait, I wonder where they get all that Kosher product from. Anyone considering eating this should call the Rabbi and see if he is using opinion #2.

Comment: @Yishai Or option 2b) bones of Nevelah aren't assur to begin with (ShA YD 99). Nothing to do with how processed it is.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Gelatin isn't just made from the bones though.

Comment: @Yishai It could be.

Comment: I personally do not consider "KD" to be a valid hekhsher.  Are there any mainstream independent authorities who do?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer KD is not tradmarked IIUC. Anyone can write it on their products.

Comment: The question asks about the reliability of this hechsher, which you haven't really addressed (or if you have, it's roundabout).  Please [edit] to directly address the question, else this will probably be removed.  Thanks.