# Who is Rabbi Dr. David I. Sheinkopf?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Can someone provide me with some details and background about Rabbi David I. Sheinkop? He's involved in kashrus hashgacha and after reading his short sefer on gelatin, he appears to me to be very knowledgeable as well as a person who bases his decisions on traditional Halachic sources. Is he accepted by the main stream of Orthodox Jews as someone who can be relied on?

Comment: Highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43760/who-certified-this-yogurt-as-kosher

Comment: What kosher organization is he apart of?

Comment: Someone's position on gelatin is orthogonal to if they can be relied upon. Many great rabbis have permitted it, and even though that ruling is unpopular in America, no one would say that affects the stature of those Poskim.

Comment: From what I've seen, Rabbi SHeinkopf is the main certifier for Dannon Yogurt products. I see Dannon sold in numerous kosher stores throughout NYC. 3 kosher markets in my area are all under the Va'ad, and, I know the Va'ad to have stringent kashrut standards imposed on all their stores; sometimes stringencies that go beyond "norm". FWIW, they are allowing the stores to sell Dannon Yogurt which is supervised by Rabbi Sheinkopf. Perhaps, this story is an indication of his trustworthiness, maybe not. You can contact OU or Star K, etc. They may give you more info.

Comment: @DanF - http://www.koshertoday.com/dannon-yogurt-returns-with-passover-products-after-two-year-absence-normanos-to-produce-greek-yogurt/ - Note that OU certifies all of their products except for the products that contain gelatin in which Rabbi David I. Sheinkopf hechshers them. Fishy, huh?

Comment: @ezra not at all, since the OU would probably be fine with fish gelatin

Comment: http://www.torahindex.com/en/Inst/institutionsDetail.aspx?index=2&instID=5633 
Olam Hatorah is not responsible for the kashrut level.
Rabbi Dr. David Sheinkopf 5768 Vintage Oaks Circle Delray Beach   33484   Florida

Comment: @DoubleAA - Was that a joke? I find it strange that the OU would certify all their products but when it came to the ones containing gelatin they had to get someone else to certify it. https://www.google.com/search?q=fishy&oq=fishy&aqs=chrome..69i57.647j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 See definition 2.

Comment: @EzraHoerster First of all, it was a hilarious joke. Second, it's not strange at all. The OU doesn't deal with most mammal-based gelatin products. They also don't deal with any Shmitta products (and many people eat those). Some things are just subject to sufficient Machloket that they don't want to deal with it. Nothing strange or suspicious or anything. It's just a company policy. For these items (as with every item) you should ask your rabbi what you should do.

Comment: @DoubleAA - It was zeyer komish. Good one! I do agree that it could very well be the OU avoiding subject to machlokes. And like everything, it is ALWAYS best to CYLOR.

Comment: The local kosher food store (under the KVH) sells Pessach desserts under his hashgacha in the main portion of the store.

Comment: Jewish individual but not Judaism?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Gelatin, this is what he says (YMMV). The hecsherim that he gives would follow his view on this matter. Other hechsherim could differ and your determination to accept him or not should be based on you rav's opinion of this matter.

[GELATIN IN JEWISH LAW](http://www.koshersupervisoryservices.com/gelatin/)
By Rabbi David I. Sheinkopf

> Gelatin produced from cattle bones or hides of even non-ritually
>   slaughtered animals is kosher in full accordance with orthodox Jewish
>   dietary laws. The reason is that only the edible parts of non-kosher
>   animals are forbidden. Bones and hides, however, which are inedible,
>   are excluded by the Talmud and Jewish Law Codes from any category of
>   foodstuffs. Therefore, after undergoing chemical pretreatments which
>   render them absolutely free of any forbidden extraneous materials,
>   bones and hides in themselves are permissible.
>
> Soaked in hydrochloric acid and/or lime for extended periods of time,
>   the raw material is reduced to pure collagen with no traces of
>   adhering flesh, marrow, or grease whatsoever. (Those who contend
>   otherwise are simply unfamiliar with the manufacturing process.)
>   Hence, the gelatin extracted from the collagenous residue of bones and
>   hides is kosher. This is true regardless of whether gelatin is
>   considered a new substance (davar hadash). Also, because it originates
>   from a non-edible substance, gelatin is pareve (neither meat nor
>   dairy.)

Comment: That argument is essentially the same as Rav Ovadia Yosef's. All the discussion you hear about the new substance Heter is only accd to the Rambam that bones are Asur Derabanan. The Rashba and ShA though don't seem to accept that.